# Tags page: to see most popular tags by week, month etc

Tags: feature-request

Feature request: To be able to see the most popular tags of a site in the `Tags` page, by week, month, etc. (similar to the feature added to the `Users` page recently).

**EDIT**: Where the count is by each tag in the tag page now, maybe there can be the count for recently on "recent" (month, week, year, etc.) views, calculated the same way as the numbers by the tags are calculated now (maybe the count should include questions all which had activity (not only new ones), because then that would mean that someone is still interested in them :) ).

Comment: Can you clarify how to decide popularity?  Most views?  Most votes?  Most questions?  Is it only for questions new that week, or should activity in existing questions count too?